# How to remove extra "\n" in output in c

Tags: c

while the output of the code is the correct one, an extra line is being printed before the answer.
How to remove the extra "\n" being printed before the output of the executed code?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int     main(void)
{
    int     nbr_words;
    char    word_1[51];
    char    word_2[51];
    int     i;

    scanf("%d\n", &nbr_words);

    char    temp_word_1[nbr_words][51];
    char    temp_word_2[nbr_words][51];

    i = 0;
    while (i < nbr_words)
    {
        scanf("%s ", word_1);
        strcpy(temp_word_1[i], word_1);
        scanf("%s", word_2);
        strcpy(temp_word_2[i], word_2);
        i++;
    }

    while (nbr_words >= 0)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n", temp_word_2[nbr_words], temp_word_1[nbr_words]);
        nbr_words--;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

output:

```
2
travail work
verite truth

truth verite
work travail
```

Comment: Don't end your `scanf` format strings with a space (and newline is a space). That might lead to problems, most commonly that you need to add extra input that is not used.

Comment: Your first print is out of bounds: `temp_word_1[nbr_words]` does not exist. Valid elements are `temp_word_1[0]` to `temp_word_1[nbr_words - 1]` (same, of course, for `temp_word_2`).

Comment: Indeed I missed that.. thx ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first print is out of bounds: `temp_word_1[nbr_words]` does not exist. Valid elements are `temp_word_1[0]` to `temp_word_1[nbr_words - 1]` (same, of course, for `temp_word_2`).

> ```
>         while (nbr_words >= 0)
>         {
>             printf("%s %s\n", temp_word_2[nbr_words], temp_word_1[nbr_words]);
>             nbr_words--;
>         }
> ```

---

```
        while (nbr_words--)
        {
            printf("%s %s\n", temp_word_2[nbr_words], temp_word_1[nbr_words]);
        }
```